# Perform segue depending on image tapped in TableViews custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Simple as my question on title. I'm trying to go to another view controller depending on the image that someone tap on my table view. Eg: If you tapped on image1 perform segue gotoview1, if you tapped on image2 perform segue gotoview2.

I have an array of the images:

```
let gameImages = [UIImage(named: "DonkeyKong"), UIImage(named: "TRex"), UIImage(named: "SuperMarioRun"), UIImage(named: "Arcades1")]
```

and this is my cell for index, I tried to perfom the segue with the func imageAction but the app will crash:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.frontImage.image = gameImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = gameTitles[indexPath.row]

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageAction:")
    cell.frontImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.frontImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    func imageAction(_ sender:AnyObject) {
        if cell.frontImage.image == UIImage(named: "DonkeyKong"){
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDonkey", sender: self)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have a custom cell where I just linked the images as an outlet and perform some basic modifications. Just saying in case this matters.

Comment: Would you mind adding crash log to your question? It will help me help you better.

Comment: 2019-02-20 14:37:27.503845-0500 TestProjectGame[31865:2947281] -[TestProjectGame.FrontViewController imageAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab56c1bb80
2019-02-20 14:37:27.516745-0500 TestProjectGame[31865:2947281] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestProjectGame.FrontViewController imageAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab56c1bb80'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
cell.imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.imageAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.imageButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.frontImage.image = gameImages[indexPath.row]
cell.title.text = gameTitles[indexPath.row]

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageAction:")
cell.frontImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.frontImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
return cell
```

}

```
func imageAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag{
        case 0:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDonkey", sender: self)
        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTRex", sender: self)
        case 2:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSuperMarioRun", sender: self)
        case 3:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToArcades1", sender: self)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

imageAction function is not member of self since is part o a tableview delegate function not self. that's why the unrecognized selector instance.
but i maybe rewrite the func using another delegate, but since you dnt  want to use the cell didselect only the image this may solve your problem.

Comment: The function throw an error when cell.frontImage.image is called, I believe this is because cell will stay inside the function CellForRowAt. 

I tried rewriting per your suggestion but with no luck either. Either way, didSelectRow will work if I click outside the image and will perform the segue and I just want to perform the segue when the image is tapped and not the entire cell. Thank you anyway!

Comment: then you can use a UIButton over the uiimage and add a target to the button i'll edit  my answer using UIbutton to reflect the use of a button.